# Why does my Ruby program not initialize multiple database connections?

Tags: ruby, oop, activerecord

I have an issue with my database connections overwriting each other.

I create two individual connections, but when I call `$db1.execute_sql`, `$db2.execute_sql` is actually what gets called.

Here is what I have:

servers.yml:

```
db1:
  adapter: jdbc
  driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  url: db_1_url
  username: my_username
  password: m_password

db2:
  adapter: jdbc
  driver: oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver
  url: db_2_url
  username: my_username
  password: m_password
```

ServerContext class:

```
class ServerContext
  def initialize (env)
    connect(env)
  end

  def connect(env)
    begin
    config = YAML.load_file("features/config/servers.yml")
    rescue
      puts "cannot load config/servers.yml"
    end
    @connection = ActiveRecord::Base
    @connection.establish_connection(config[env])
  end

  def execute_sql(sql_string)
    @connection.connection.execute(sql_string)
  end
```

Database setup:

```
def connect_databases
  $db1 = ServerContext.new('db1')
  $db2 = ServerContext.new('db2')
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the new activeRecord stores connections in a hash based on Class name.  So each time I was overwriting the connection in ActiveRecord (not in the class itself).  See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html and look under Connection to multiple databases in different models.

Answer (score 1):

You're doing

```
@connection = ActiveRecord::Base
```

I think as you're using the same static method of the class two times for the connection, the second time it simply rewrites the previous connection.

Create a class that extends from ActiveRecord::Base for each connection:

```
class DB1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end

class DB2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
end
```

Then, in your connect method:

```
case config[env]
when 'db1'
  @connection = DB1
when 'db2'
  @connection = DB2
end
```

Comment: Is this the case even though I'm instantiating a new version of ServerContext for each database connection?

Comment: Yes, it's at the class level. You need to call DB1.establish_connection and DB2.establish_connection as well

Answer (score 1):

The current connection is a thread local variable so you can only set it to one thing at a time - http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/ConnectionPool.html
You need two separate classes that inherit from ActiveRecord::Base to do what you want